# Encryption using GPGME in C

Tags: c, gpgme

I am currently working on a project that requires file encryption using GPGME. I have found this sandbox code and am trying to get it going to help understand the subject. I am getting held up on line 46 with the gpgme_get_key() function and it is not allowing the code to continue. I am having a hard time finding documentation on what might be going wrong. I think that the problem is coming from that a key is not properly being generated.

```
#include <gpgme.h>
#include <gpg-error.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//define INSERT_FAILURE

int bang(const gpgme_error_t err)
{
fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", gpgme_strerror(err), gpgme_strsource(err));
return err;
}
int bang_(const char *e)
{
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e);
return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
gpgme_check_version(NULL);

gpgme_error_t err;
gpgme_data_t plain, cipher;
gpgme_ctx_t ctx;
gpgme_key_t recp[2] = {NULL, NULL};
gpgme_encrypt_flags_t flags = GPGME_ENCRYPT_ALWAYS_TRUST;

char *plaintext = "foo bar\0";
char *fp = "845B80B9AD12DB400CE534F6837EED10F97A36A1";
char *result_file = "./result.gpg";
char *verify_file = "./result";
size_t max_buflen = 2048, buflen;
char *buf = malloc(max_buflen * sizeof(char));
FILE *fh = NULL;
fprintf(stderr, "Got to line: %d\n", __LINE__);
err = gpgme_new(&ctx);
if (err)
    return bang(err);
fprintf(stderr, "Got to line: %d\n", __LINE__);
gpgme_set_armor(ctx, 1);
fprintf(stderr, "Got to line: %d\n", __LINE__);
err = gpgme_get_key(ctx, fp, &recp[0], 0);
if (err)
    return bang(err);
fprintf(stderr, "Got to line: %d\n", __LINE__);

err = gpgme_data_new_from_mem(&plain, plaintext, strlen(plaintext), 0); //look at
if (err)
    return bang(err);
fprintf(stderr, "Got to line: %d\n", __LINE__);

err = gpgme_data_new(&cipher);
if (err)
    return bang(err);
fprintf(stderr, "Got to line: %d\n", __LINE__);

err = gpgme_op_encrypt(ctx, recp, flags, plain, cipher);
if (err)
    return bang(err);

gpgme_data_seek(cipher, 0, SEEK_SET);
buflen = gpgme_data_read(cipher, buf, max_buflen);
if (1 > buflen || buflen == max_buflen)
    return bang_("Failed to read ciphertext");

fh = fopen(result_file, "w");
if (!fh)
    bang_("failed to open result_file");

fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), buflen, fh);
fclose(fh);
fh = NULL;

memset(buf, 0, max_buflen);
snprintf(buf, max_buflen - 1, "gpg --output %s -d %s", verify_file, result_file);
system(buf);

memset(buf, 0, max_buflen);
fh = fopen(verify_file, "rb");
if (!fh)
    return bang_("failed to open verify_file");

buflen = fread(buf, sizeof(char), max_buflen, fh);
fclose(fh);

if (buflen < 1 || buflen == max_buflen)
    return bang_("Failed to read result file");

#ifdef INSERT_FAILURE
buf[buflen - 1] = '\0';
#endif

if (strncmp(buf, plaintext, strlen(plaintext)) != 0)
    return bang_("Decrypted text is different from original plaintext");

return 0;
}
```